# Fail2ban error 'database is locked' when trying to start / restart it

Tags: centos, fail2ban, webmin

I am currently reinstalling fail2ban to have a fresh version, because i've modified it quite a lot of time since I installed it for the first time, and I wanted to default settings for it.

Once installed, and when I check the logs, it seems that the jails cannot be started/modified because "database is locked".

```
2016-05-24 19:09:41,012 fail2ban.transmitter    [30865]: WARNING Command ['start', 'ssh-iptables'] has failed. Received OperationalError('database is locked',)
2016-05-24 19:09:46,178 fail2ban.transmitter    [30865]: WARNING Command ['start', 'proftpd-iptables'] has failed. Received OperationalError('database is locked',)
```

I run on CentOS 7 + Webmin. I've looked around and googled it, but I couldnt encounter one single fail2ban related error with the error "database is locked".
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tried to restart the server first ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 yes, the result is the same.